# How do I refresh the OAuth Token when using Google Cloud SQL JDBC Driver?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-java-client, google-cloud-sql

I am using the Google Cloud SQL driver on a Google Compute Instance to persist results to a Google Cloud SQL database during a long running batch process.

At some point, perhaps after the first hour of running, the oAuth token seems to expire, and all subsequent requests fail with:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: 400 Bad Request
{
   "error" : "unauthorized_client"
}
at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.googleapi.RpcGoogleApi.newOpenConnectionIOException(RpcGoogleApi.java:168)
at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.googleapi.RpcGoogleApi.openConnection(RpcGoogleApi.java:104)
at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.SqlProtoClient.openConnection(SqlProtoClient.java:58)
at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:66)
at com.google.cloud.sql.Driver.connectImpl(Driver.java:109)
at com.google.cloud.sql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:98)
at com.google.cloud.sql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:31)
```

I can abort the process, run google_sql.sh from the client line and the restart the batch process, and the connection will be fine until the token expires again.

Apparently, the command line tool is doing something to refresh the token before connecting; how do I do the same for my batch process?

Comment: What is google_sql.sh?

Comment: @pinoyyid google_sql.sh is a command line utility provided in the google cloud sdk, which launches com.google.cloud.sql.tool.googleapi.SqlTool. This apparently does something to refresh the auth token, but it's not documented.

Comment: got it. I'll do some digging

Comment: If I find the source code, I'll have a proper look. In the meantime, from your question I would call it as a bug in the SDK that it isn't refreshing the access token, which as you say, expires on the hour. There is one workaround you could try. It's possible that the bug only exists in command line mode (on the basis that they don't expect a single command to last more than one hour). It might be that in interactive mode, they have the refresh logic on the basis that an interactive session could be long lived. So try running in interactive mode and pipe your commands in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client id and secret of the Cloud SQL tool need to be provided to the JDBC driver because we are using tokens which that particular tool has retrieved: https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/external

```
Properties props = new Properties()
props.put("oauth2ClientId", "32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com");
props.put("oauth2ClientSecret", "ZmssLNjJy2998hD4CTg2ejr2");
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:google:rdbms://instance_name/database_name", props);
```

If you're using Hibernate as I was, you can add this to the persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="renjin-repo" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
  ...
  <properties>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>

    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.google.cloud.sql.Driver"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:google:rdbms://project:instance/database_name"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.oauth2ClientId" value="32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.oauth2ClientSecret" value="ZmssLNjJy2998hD4CTg2ejr2"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="0" />
  </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud SQL team are working on improving the connectivity from Compute Engine. If you send this question to google-cloud-sql-discuss@googlegroups.com, they will be able to follow up.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-sql-discuss